# Running uvicorn as WindowsService, signal only works in main thread

Tags: python, windows, service, signals, uvicorn

When launching a uvicorn app in a windows service, the service failed to start with error indicating that signal can only be handled in the main thread.

Here is the error message catched in the event log:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "site-packages\win32\lib\win32serviceutil.py", line 839, in SvcRun
  File "WindowsService.py", line 49, in SvcDoRun
  File "site-packages\uvicorn\main.py", line 279, in run
  File "site-packages\uvicorn\main.py", line 307, in run
  File "asyncio\base_events.py", line 584, in run_until_complete
  File "site-packages\uvicorn\main.py", line 319, in serve
  File "site-packages\uvicorn\main.py", line 459, in install_signal_handlers
  File "signal.py", line 47, in signal
ValueError: signal only works in main thread
```

The project works fin un debugging mode.

```sh
.\dist\WindowsService.exe debug
```

No parameters allow me to specify to not handle signals.

Here is how I launch prgramatically to uvicorn app:

```py
        uvicorn.run(app.main, 
                    host=config['server']['host'], 
                    port=config['server']['port'], 
                    log_level=config['server']['loglevel'], 
                    reload=False)
```

The application is compiled ina frozen executable using **win32serviceutil.ServiceFramework**

```sh
pyinstaller -F --hidden-import=win32timezone --additional-hooks-dir pyinstaller-hooks WindowsService.py
```

I expected to launch the windows service and have uvicorn application running.

Comment: The full source code is accessible at: https://github.com/kbeaugrand/PythonFastApi

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution, that implies to have a console app called by the Windows service. 
With that inside my console app I've the opportunity to work on the main thread and launch the uvicorn as requested.

Sub process calling is made by:

```py
 def SvcDoRun(self):
        _log('has started')

        # determine if application is a script file or frozen exe
        if getattr(sys, 'frozen', False):
            application_path = os.path.dirname(sys.executable)
        elif __file__:
            application_path = os.path.dirname(__file__)

        exe_name = os.path.join(application_path, self._app_exe_name_)
        _log('launchin subprocess for {exe_name}'.format(exe_name=exe_name))
        p = subprocess.Popen([exe_name])

        _log('is running in subprocess id {process_id}'.format(process_id=p.pid))

        while True:               
            result = win32event.WaitForSingleObject(self._stop_event, 5000)

            if result == win32event.WAIT_OBJECT_0:
                # stop requested                  
                _log('is stopping')
                p.kill()
                break

        _log('has stopped')
```

Comment: Source code is availiable at:https://github.com/kbeaugrand/PythonFastApi

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and didn't like your solution of running a subprocess. I found https://github.com/encode/uvicorn/issues/526 which explains the issue. My workaround:

```
config = uvicorn.Config(app, ...)
server = uvicorn.Server(config=config)
# According to https://github.com/encode/uvicorn/issues/526, on Python 3.8+ you MIGHT also need:
# asyncio.set_event_loop_policy(asyncio.WindowsSelectorEventLoopPolicy())
# But in my case it didn't seem to be necessary
server.install_signal_handlers = lambda: None  # this is the necessary workaround
server.run()
```